# Fileinput issue in ActiveForm when updating via Yii 2

Tags: file-upload, yii, yii2, active-form

I am using Yii2 framwork. My file upload function worked well when I upload a single img, while when I click the posed article and I only want to update the post again(Suppose I didn't want to update the img, I only want to update other contents). But I found my uploaded file were replaced with an empty value(varchar type) when I click view. my uploaded img can't show out.

I do tried to fixed by myself as below, But the existing file value can't be saved when I click the submit button.

```
                <?php

                    if (($post->file) != "") {
                    echo $form->field($post, 'file')->textInput()->hint('My currently uploaded file')->label('My Photo') ;

                }
                else{
                    echo $form->field($post, 'file')->fileInput()->hint('To upload a new file')->label('My Photo') ;
                }

                ?>
```

When I click submit button, my existing file was gone.
Is there any good way to fix it.
Thanks for your opinions in advance.

Comment: Please show us your `$post` model

Comment: Why no check in the controller if an image was uploaded? And skip the image processing when there is no image uploded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another variable in your model for upload a file.

For example use `file_field` name for get file from submitted and store in `file` field.

```php
class PostModel extends Model
{

    /**
     *
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    public $file_field;
    
    public function rules() {
        return [
            ['file_field', 'file'],
        ];
    }
}
```

```php
echo $form->field($post, 'file_field')->fileInput()->hint('To upload a new file')->label('My Photo') ;
```

```php
$post->file_field = UploadedFile::getInstance($post, 'file_field');
```

For upload new file check the `file_field`:

```php
if ($post->file_field) {
    // $post->file  old file
    // Save $post->file_field and store name in $post->file
}
```

Comment: I'll try this way later. thanks for your reply in advance.

Comment: `$model->oldAttributes["file"]` ’, I found this oldattr value also could be used to identify the file field value.

Comment: @NanoSix $model->file is your old file before save new and store again in $model->file. after save $model->file_field you can set new file name to old: $model->file = $newFileName

Answer (score 1):

Add a rule to your model rules:

```
[['file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
```

and check for an empty upload in your controller:

```
if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
    $ok = true;
    // process your other fields...
    ...
    // process image file only if there is one
    $post->file= UploadedFile::getInstance($post, 'file');
    if ($post->file && $post->upload()) {
        
    }
    if ($ok) {
        return $this->redirect(...);
    }
}
```

See [Yii2 docs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-uploadedfile) and the [Yii2 guide](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/the-tutorial-on-how-to-upload-an-image-to-yii2-model/123464) for detailed infos about file upload.

Comment: I'll try it right now. I am new to Yii2. Thank you.